# Why is a device file not created?

Tags: usb, kernel, modprobe

Upon insertion of a mass USB storage device like an external hard drive or a flash drive, `dmesg -w` notes its insertion but no corresponding file such as `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb` is created.

Comment: `journalctl --follow` as you insert the device will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to irregular configurations, the kernel doesn't know what to do upon insertion of said medium. Load usb-storage:

```
$ sudo modprobe usb-storage
```

This instructs the kernel on what to do.

Comment: There's something you don't include here. By default, Ubuntu (and any other modern Linux distro) will do this just fine by themselves. There may be reasons why it fails, but in that case it's normally better to figure out why auto-discovery of hardware fails, than to manually insert modules.

Comment: The kennel appears to detect it just fine if `journalctl` and `dmesg` is any indication, however, the module was not automatically loaded for some reason and due to no indication of such a problem, I was looking for solutions in completely unrelated areas.